# Reference request: Student-selected grading schemes?

Tags: reference-request, grading

I am interested in student learning. However, because I work in a university system, I generally need to assign a grade (A through F) to the students' work. So I need to assess student learning.

I generally use a variety of assessment techniques : quizzes, projects, exams, class participation, etc.

At the beginning of each course, I publish in the syllabus how the grades for each of these assessment techniques will be combined to form the final grade for the course.

Because students respond to each of these different assessment techniques differently, I'm wondering how fair I am being when making a blanket application of them to the student body.

What I'm wondering is: do there exist studies on allowing students to determine the weighting on their assessment, or even the form of their assessment, and whether this affects the students' learning outcomes?

I have [found this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03075079.2017.1290062?journalCode=cshe20), but it seems mostly to ask whether a pass-fail grading scheme is better than an A-F scheme.